# iPhone and Mac "Mail" app emails sync not working...?

Tags: macos, iphone, mail.app, email, imap

I just bought a brand new Macbook Pro 15" and I already have an iPhone 4. I'm using Hotmail (now called Outlook) for email management. Since I'm using a Macbook now, I want to use Mail.app to manage my emails since I have multiple email accounts.

Here's my problem :

I have set my Hotmail account in Mail, and everything's working well. But When I read the email (of the same email account) on my iPhone, it's still mark as unread on my Macbook Pro after reading it on my iPhone.
But if I go on hotmail.com and log in my account, if I read a new email on my iphone that appears as unread in Hotmail, it will change as "read" in hotmail. So looks like the emails are synced.

I've made some research and looks like IMAP emails accounts can do what I need. Hotmail seems to be a POP3 mail server.
But if when logged in hotmail website, it works with my iPhone, why can't it work using the Mac Mail app? Some website seems to be saying that you can't do what I need with Hotmail (only Gmails, and other IMAP mail server)...and some say it'S possible.

Thanks a lot!

(I'm on Macbook Pro 2012, OSX 10.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone uses the 'modern' Exchange ActiveSync (which is a mobile-only protocol) to sync with Hotmail, which explains why read emails are synced to Hotmail.com.

[The only other protocol Hotmail/Outlook.com supports is POP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app). Unfortunately they do not support IMAP, so POP is as good as you're going to get.

Comment: Ok, I see. So basicly, it's not possible to sync my iPhone mails with my Mail app on my mac since it's POP protocol?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thanks a lot for your quick and clear answer!

Comment: What if I create a Gmail account, and that I foward my hotmail emails to the Gmail one, and that I setup the Gmail account in my iPhone and Macbook? Would this work?

Comment: I have my hotmail account set up as an IMAP and a SMTP account (I didn't do it that way, the Mail.app chose to do that...idk why), but the point is, it does what you are seeking for me. Did you set up the mailbox through the app on both devices and is you iPhone fully updated?